# CSS Float Positioning Questions

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm having some trouble getting two elements to float over each other. How can I get two elements to float over each other?

This is what I want:
  [image]

They keep on bumping into their margins. Once I get their positions properly down on the CSS I'm planning to make them invert colors (#C12525 & #C12C2C).

I'm pretty new to this and thought I'd ask the community for help. Gonna keep experimenting with this but curious to see what people have to say.

Comment: Can you show your code, and what you've tried?

Comment: You can't use `float` to place two elements on top of each other. You could either use `position: absolute;` on one of the elements, or in my opinion the simplest option would be to use `margin-top` with a negative value on the second element.

Answer (score 0):

Use negative numbers. This question is probably asked a lot. Use either of these on your CSS page:

overflow.css

```
.first{
  margin: 0px;
}
.second{
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

test.html

```
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="overlap.css" />
  <body>
    <div class="first">
      <h1>KNOCK KNOCK</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      <h1>INTERRUPTING COW</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `margin-top: -0px;` is unnecessary and the second element should have either `margin: -50px 0 0;` or `margin-top: -50px;`. `-50px` all around isn't the best in most of the cases.

Comment: Totally correct, sorry about that, correcting.
I don't know what other things he has in his code but clearing it in this example could be useful if he wants to check it in his running config.

Comment: I would also add that if you add the classes to the `headings` directly, you can remove the `div` parents. That's two elements less. Oh and on a page you shouldn't have two `h1` headings.